# If I just install Ubuntu Server from a CD will it wipe any partitions?

Tags: server

I want to install Ubuntu server from a CD but it doesn't say anything about partitions or anything. How does that work? Does it even use a partition and if so which one will it use and will it ruin the data on that or any other partition? Or can is there a way I can just run it from my desktop? I didn't see any links other than the one for the .iso file.

Answer (score 0):

- Installation of the server version is non graphical.
- You will be prompted for partitioning with a text based partitioner. Examples screens:

[image]

- Of course it uses a partition.
- It will use the one you tell it to use.
- It will do with data what you tell it to do. Delete a partition and the data on that partition is gone. Same if you format a partition.
- You do not run it from a desktop; you run the CD/DVD and install from there. And it is text based; not a graphical interface like the desktop version.

[If you need guidance installing a server version please have a look at this guide](http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2013/02/manual-disk-partition-guide-for-ubuntu-server-edition.html).

But of course you start by making a backup of the files you deem important. That will make it possible to get your files back in place if you make a mistake.

Comment: ok thanks for your help. The installation system didn't quite make it clear whether it was going to be using a partition or some how installed on the desktop version from the CD or something. Is there a desktop server version? one that I can install right onto / through my desktop version? Thanks again for your help!